# Discord Bot in Python Reaction Response

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I want that when someone reacts to one emoji the bot writes as a log on chat like this:

> @Santa has press 4️⃣

I tried to make it but I'm stuck.

```
import discord
import time
import random
from discord.ext import commands

client = discord.Client()
bot  = client.user

if message.content.startswith('ººrandgame'):
    original = await message.channel.send('Discover the number I my mind...')

    uno = await original.add_reaction('1️⃣')
    dos = await original.add_reaction('2️⃣')
    tres = await original.add_reaction('3️⃣')
    cuatro = await original.add_reaction('4️⃣')
    cinco = await original.add_reaction('5️⃣')
    seis = await original.add_reaction('6️⃣')
    siete = await original.add_reaction('7️⃣')
    ocho = await original.add_reaction('8️⃣')
    nueve = await original.add_reaction('9️⃣')
    diez = await original.add_reaction('')
    numbers = ['1️⃣','2️⃣','3️⃣','4️⃣','5️⃣','6️⃣','7️⃣','8️⃣','9️⃣','']
    #this part fails::
if(reaction.emoji == "1️⃣"):
            await message.channel.send(author + "has press 1️⃣")

#the same idea with the other numbers 





time.sleep(15)
finalnum = random.choice(numbers)
await message.channel.send('My number is: ' + finalnum)
print(finalnum)

client.run('blabla')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `reaction_wait_for`, this will always wait for the author of the message input of the specified reaction.

Below I've made a simple user reaction command but I'll leave it up to you how you would further like to improve it.

```
message = await ctx.send("React to a number")

one = '1️⃣'
two = '2️⃣'

await message.add_reaction(one)
await message.add_reaction(two)

    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in [one, two]

        member = ctx.author
        while True:
            try:
                reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=600.0, check=check)

                if str(reaction.emoji) == one:
                    await ctx.send("You choose 1")
                                
                if str(reaction.emoji) == two:
                    await ctx.send("You choose 2")
```

In your code, I would also reccomend using `asyncio.sleep(15)` instead of `time.sleep`, as this causes the whole bot to stop, meaning no one can use it at all.
Make sure to `import asyncio`

You can also set it as a command, instead of using `if message.content.startswith('ººrandgame'):` , You can use

```
@client.command()
async def ººrandgame(ctx):

.... Rest of your code ...
```

Comment: @Dharman & Cohen thanks so much for answering me. But when I tryed your code, I have a problem, a console extract: 
{note: was defined as:    client = discord.Client() }
>>>  client.run('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
>>>  ^
>>>IndentationError: unexpected unindent

I open a new .py for testing and the error it's the same. I will paste the test code in another comment. From already thank you very much ;).

Comment: @Santa It's not from this code. You have incorrect indentation in your own code. Probably around the line `if(reaction.emoji == "1️⃣"):`.

Answer (score 0):

## Ibidem, I think that something is missing

```
import discord
import os
import random
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands


client = discord.Client()
horaact = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
os.system('cls')
os.system('color 1f')

@client.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("Encendido")
    print("logged in as {0.user}".format(client))


@client.command()
async def ººrandgame(ctx):
    message = await ctx.send("React to a number")

    one = '1️⃣'
    two = '2️⃣'

    await message.add_reaction(one)
    await message.add_reaction(two)
    def check(reaction, user):
        return user == ctx.author and str(reaction.emoji) in [one, two]

        member = ctx.author
        while True:
            try:
                reaction, user = await client.wait_for("reaction_add", timeout=600.0, check=check)
                if str(reaction.emoji) == one:
                    await ctx.send("You choose 1")
                                        
                if str(reaction.emoji) == two:
                    await ctx.send("You choose 2")
client.run('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')
```

#### Remember, this is not the original code, it's just a test for trying your funtion